# Can we deduce $f(x)=$const from $f(px)=f(x)$

Tags: functions

Let $f:R\rightarrow R$ be a continuous function.
There exists a $p>0$, s.t. $f(px)=f(x),p\neq1$ for all $x\in R$.

Can we prove that $f(x)$ is a constant function?

Comment: What about $p=1$?

Comment: @JohnDouma Oh, I mean $p\neq 1$. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Sorry I missed that it has to be contiuous

Comment: Wlog p<1. Otherwise $f(x)=f(\frac{1}{p}x)$. I think you can then establish that it's constant on $[0, \infty]$ . There's a lemma in real analysis which says that if $a_n \to a$ and $f$ is continuous then $f(a_n) \to f(a)$. So, you can consider the sequence $p,p^2,...$. But now repeating this for the same sequence scaled by some arbitrary factor (i.e $ ap, ap^2,ap^3,...$) and since limits are unique, $f(1)=f(a)$ and so on.

Comment: And repeat for [-\infty, 0]

Comment: Just for fun if we allow one single point where $f$ is not continuous then we can construct other examples than the constant function. For example the function $f(x) = \sin(2\pi \log_p|x|)$ with $f(0)$ arbitrary satisfy $f(px) = f(x)$ for all $x$ ...but fails to be continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider separately the cases $p<1$ and $p>1$. For the case that $p<1$, note that
$$f(p^nx)=f(x).$$
What happens if you pass to the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$?
Can you repeat this idea for $p>1$?
Hope this helps!

Comment: Great - glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes if $|p| \not = 1$.

> Suppose $|p|\not = 1$. If $p=0$, we're done. If $p\not= 0$, without loss of generality (because we can replace $p$ by $\frac{1}{p}$), we can assume that $0<|p|<1$. Take $x\in \mathbb R$. $p^nx \to 0$ when $n\to +\infty$ so since $f$ is continuous $f(p^nx)\to f(0)$ when $n\to +\infty$. But by our hypothesis, the sequence $f(p^nx)$ is constant (because $f(p^nx)=f(p^{n-1}x)=\dots=f(px)=f(x)$) so that $f(p^nx)=f(0)$ for any $n$ and in particular $f(x)=f(0)$.